# How to perform likelihood ratio test for linear regression in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to do a likelihood ratio test to compare nested models in SAS. I am very new to SAS and am only familiar with `PROC REG` to conduct a regression analysis. Do you have any ideas on how I can find the likelihood ratio test or how I would start?

I know how to do a LR test with logistic regression but it seems to automatically come up with the `PROC LOGISTIC` function.

Any help would be appreciated!